# Adding typescript support to a new node app

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm creating from scratch a simple `node` app with `typescript` support. After standard bootstrapping:

```
npm init --yes
```

I'm installing the `typescript` package just like that:

```
npm install typescript
```

but after that I'm getting an old *2.9.2* version! When i uninstall the typescript package:

```
npm uninstall typescript
```

and install it once again:

```
npm install typescript
```

i eventually get the latest version - *4.2.4*!
My question is why does it install the old version in the first time, not the most recent!?

Comment: There's no reason for such things until you specify the version. I've never come across any such thing so far. Can you please provide some more info such as OS platform etc. 
There's a possiblity that for first scenario, node has installed typescript from local cache.

Comment: @Mahesh Visual Studio Code on Win 10. How can I check if it's installing from the local cache?